# Protos in .NET project reported to be missing at compile time when imported in another .NET project

Tags: .net, grpc

I am writing a .NET 5 application whose models are defined in Proto files.
This should allow me to compile them into C# models and use them for DB operations. They should also be able to be imported and used in a gRPC server project (of the same solution) to communicate these models to gRPC clients written in Java and Python. But these cross-project imports fail at compile-time.

The structure of the solution:

```
Solution
- Project 'Protos' - defines Proto models
- Project 'DataAccess' - imports 'Protos' and uses compiled models for DB operations
- Project 'Server'
   - imports 'DataAccess' to retrieve DB records; and
   - imports 'Protos' to communicate these records to gRPC clients
```

Service definition for gRPC communication in project `Server` (`/Users/[username]/dev/Solution/Server/Protos/MessagingService.proto`):

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "Protos/Message.proto";

option csharp_namespace = "Server";

service Messaging {
  rpc Communicate (MessageRequest) returns (MessageResponse);
}

message MessageRequest {
  string Name = 1;
}

message MessageResponse {
  Message Message = 1;
}
```

Project-level imports as defined in `/Users/[username]/dev/Solution/Server/Server.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\MessagingService.proto" GrpcServices="Server" />
    <!-- Proto imported from sister project 'Protos' -->
    <Protobuf Include="..\Proto\Protos\Message.proto" Link="Protos\Message.proto" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc.AspNetCore" Version="2.34.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Proto\Proto.csproj">
      <GlobalPropertiesToRemove></GlobalPropertiesToRemove>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Imported proto (shown to be present both as `/Users/[username]/dev/Solution/Protos/Protos/Message.proto` and `/Users/[username]/dev/Solution/Server/Protos/Message.proto`):

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "Proto";

message Message {
    string Id = 1;
    string Name = 2;
}
```

This setup looks sound until compilation. That is, `Message.proto` appears in project `Server` in the `Protos` folder.
**However, building project `Server` fails with the following messages:**

```
Protos/Message.proto : error : File not found. [/Users/[username]/dev/Solution/Server/Server.csproj]
Protos/MessagingService.proto(3,1): error : Import "Protos/Message.proto" was not found or had errors. [/Users/[username]/dev/Solution/Server/Server.csproj]
Protos/MessagingService.proto(16,3): error : "Message" is not defined. [/Users/[username]/dev/Solution/Server/Server.csproj]
```

Considering the duplicated `Message.proto` file appears in the file browser of Visual Studio for Mac both in `Protos` and `Server`, this error message appears to make no sense.

I have tried different things in the imports:

- For the import statement in `MessagingService.proto`, I tried different relative paths and both `/` and `\` but this is the only form in which that line does not error.
- For the import tag in `Server.csproj`, I tried adding more attributes like `ProtoRoot` and `GrpcServices` but they do not make any difference.

Comment: .proto files that have dependencies between themselves (e.g. A.proto.  does `import "foo/bar/b.proto"` are easier to process if they are in one common directory tree that matches the paths that are being used in import statements (otherwise protobuf compiler has no way of finding the .proto file that are being imported).   If your .proto files reside in 2 different directory trees, you'll have to force the protobuf compiler consider multiple `-I` include paths. (e.g by using the newly introduced AdditionalProtocArguments).

Comment: Also, I'd highly recommend creating a class library that contains all your .proto files and handles the entire .proto code generation and other projects would simply depend on this class library that already has the generated code in it. It will save you a whole lot of trouble and complexity.